# How to stream audio with 'video/x-ms-asf' content-type in Android?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem with MediaPlayer in Android. It can't stream with 'video/x-ms-asf' format.

Could anyone help me or have any sample code to play it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to play these types of streams you need to use a library such as FFmpeg to decode the audio and feed the raw bytes to AudioTrack.

ServeStream is able to play these types of streams. You can view the source code [here](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/servestream/code/trunk).

Comment: It can't play. It just display toast 'Selected playlist is empty.' even I enabled FFmpeg-based player.

Comment: Sorry, change http ://khiptv.org:44412/RC_FM95 to mmsh://khiptv.org:44412/RC_FM95 and it will work.